# Cakephp get longest unmodified entries

Tags: cakephp, model

I have a model A that

```
$hasMany = array('B' => array('order' => 'B.created DESC'), 
                 'C' => array('order' => 'C.created ASC')
           );
```

So now i want to fetch the 5 most desolated entries of A(B,C) from my database that did not get modified the longest time(including B and C 'modified'-field).

How do i do that?

/EDIT: To explain it in other words:
Assume i have a model User that has information like name, adress, email etc.
A User also has many model Post on his page. And he has many model Other on his page too. 
So we have a relationship of 1:n in User:Post and User:Other
Now i want to fetch those 5 User of my User, whose highest 'modified' value (User.modified, Post.modified or Other.modified) is one of they five lowest of all Users.
In other words: The 5 User who did not update their profile for the longest time.

Comment: so you want the 5 oldest entries by a last modified date for Model A? and then include the 5 oldest relations with those entries?

Comment: Please try to clarify - hard to tell exactly what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: Your use of the word desolate seems arbitrary.

Comment: i explained it better...

Answer (score 0):

I foresee some data inconsistencies in the future with this technique. I would do it this way.

Add field to user table called `lastactivity`
In AppController.php add beforeSave function

```
public function beforeSave() {
   $save_data = $this->data;
   if(isset($save_data['User']['modified']) || isset($save_data['Post']['modified'] || isset($save_data['Other']['modified']))){
      $data = array();
      $data['User']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
      $data['User']['lastactivity'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
      $this->User->save($data);
   }

}
```